# Specify arguments of Typescript function callback

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a callback currently defined like so:

```
onShow: Function;
```

And is called like so:

```
if (this.onShow) {
    this.onShow({ $currentPosition: this.currentLatLngPosition });
}
```

The main issue with this is that its not typesafe. How can I change the signature of `onShow` to have better type safety?

I found out I could define it a little better like so

```
onShow: () => void;
```

But I could not figure out how to get the correct function arguments in there. This doesnt work:

```
onShow: ({ $currentPosition: google.maps.LatLng }) => void;
```

Note the weird json parameter syntax is an Angular component callback requirement.

Comment: You can find more information about defining function signatures here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
interface Config {
    $currentPosition: string; // Or whatever the type of the property is.
}

type myFunc = (config: Config) => void;
```

You do not have to create an interface:

```
type myFunc = (config: { $currentPosition:string }) => void;
```